# Why Number.MAX_VALUE does not evaluate to Infinity

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

The IEEE-754 standard states that when overflow occurs, the result may evaluate to either `Infinity` or `MAX_VALUE`. As I've been recommended a few times already I decided to see what ECMAScript standard says about it. I found this under [Applying the Additive Operators to Numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-additive-operators-to-numbers)

> If the magnitude is too large to represent, the operation overflows
>   and the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign.

But testing it gives `MAX_VALUE` instead of `Infinity`, why?

```
Number.MAX_VALUE+100000000 // evaluates to Number.MAX_VALUE
```

However, this evaluates to `Infinity`:

```
Number.MAX_VALUE+Number.MAX_VALUE // evaluates to Infinity
```

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I'm guessing it has to do with the approximation of that value and the loss of precision allowing it to represent a large set of values.

Comment: @squint, yeah, that's what I'm thinking myself, but it's interesting how and why the decision to round the result or to store as Infinity is made

Comment: If you add `Number.MAX_VALUE + Math.pow(10, 291)`, you don't get `Infinity`, but you do with `Number.MAX_VALUE + Math.pow(10, 292)`. The power of ten was arrived at by taking the value `1.7976931348623157e+308` and removing the shown decimal places from the 308.